# How can I use ServiceHost (System.ServiceModel) in Silverlight 4? (c#)

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, bing-maps

I am trying to use a WCF example in Silverlight app (I want to accept requests to insert datapoints on a Sliverlight Bing map.

I am new to Silverlight and .NET.  So far I have a Bing map and can add pushpins.  What i want is to accept interprocess communications to insert pushpins from another app.

Following some web examples on WCF I tried using ServiceHost (System.ServiceModel), but apparently that is not available in a silverlight app?

I am confused.  How do I get data to a silverlight application?

This is a really really simple example - all i want to do is add a pushpin at a latitude/longitude.

EDIT

What I am trying to do is add pushpins/data to a Bing map (a silverlight app) when a different process ets updated/notified of some event with a location.  I understand now that silverlight is local to the client machine and is sandboxed - but I still need to get some event triggered on a client to the silverlight app somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to work the other way -

`ServiceHost` is intended to "host" the service - it's what creates the server side of a WCF connection.  Silverlight, given its sandbox, can only act as a service *client*.

You're other process will need to use `ServiceHost`.  It can then serve data to your Silverlight client (the client can connect and request them).

Comment: My silverlight app needs to get notified of events/requests/things that happen.  How do i go from the client to the wcf to silverlight?  I can't imagine I want to Poll in the silverlight app...

Comment: @Tim You can either poll, or (better) look into duplex connections, callbacks, or events.  I'd recommend reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight runs locally in the web browser. It is sandboxed for security reasons. A Silverlight application cannot act as a web service itself. It, however, can talk to other web services, usually running on the same server that served the Silverlight application to the client browser. A common choice is a WCF web service written in with full (non-silverlight) .NET framework.

Another application could talk to a web service on a server that the Silverlight client is also using. You can exchange data that way.

Comment: But how does the WCF service notify the silverlight instance/app of the event?

Comment: Polling would be the easiest way. There is also duplex communications in WCF, that would allow for a sort-of "push" notification. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: (I guess I should have scrolled up to see the other answer with the same suggestion...)